# node-webkit read full path of files from directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I tried the below code in NW.js to read in all files with full path under a given folder but not working. What's wrong? Thanks.

```js
function chooseFiles() {
    var files = $('#fileDialog')[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
        console.log(files[i].path);
    }
}
chooseFiles('#fileDialog');
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileDialog" nwdirectory />
```

Comment: Kevin, can you clarify what's "not working"?  This is vague.  What output do you see?  What error messages?

Comment: @jmort253, thanks for your reply. When I select the folder (Choose File -> <Folder> -> OK) it displays the folder name in the input dialog but it does not print out the files within this folder in the Console. I would like to get all full path of these files. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5827895/552792 Does this help? You may need to read the files within the directory using some other method.

Comment: @jmort253, thanks for the link. It works perfectly in app.js for node.js but for NW.js in my index.html I have a script tags to do the same but couldn't get to run successfully. It seems for NW.js I have to run `npm install fs` first due to `Uncaught ReferenceError: path is not defined` but still no go. Per [link](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-Node-modules) it should work but not. Any ideas how to use this module in NW.js? Thanks.

Comment: Also, please check out this [link](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/File-dialogs). I have the impression that NW.js has a built-in module/fn for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're using exactly the code that you pasted here, but it doesn't appear to be doing anything *when the user actually chooses something*.  If you were to pick something using the input *then* call `chooseFiles()` it should work.  At least it did in my nw.js app I quickly set up.

If you want the files to appear in `console.log()` when the user completes their selection, I think you should be able to do it using the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#fileDialog").on("change", function () {
            var files = $(this)[0].files;
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            console.log(files[i].path);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileDialog" nwdirectory />
</body>
</html>
```

If you want the files to be logged immediately when user selects a directory using the file dialog, I think the `on("change")` might be what you're looking for.  It worked for me using nw.js v0.12 so give it a shot and see if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi thetoast, thanks for your time. I am using the same nw.js version too. I tried your code with a fresh nw.js v0.12 but still not able to print the files. In console the only line it printed is the selected folder path. I also tried with two diff jquery versions (v1.9.1 and v2.1.3). Still not sure why it's not working for me. I am on Win7 if that makes any diff. Thanks.

Comment: @KevinH. Does it make any difference if you use `webkitdirectory` instead of `nwdirectory`?

Comment: `webkitdirectory` returns the dir path like `nwdirectory`. I will accept your first answer because it led me to the right direction. Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood how nwdirectory works. NW doc states "nwdirectory is a bit similar to webkitdirectory because it let user select a directory too, **but it will not enumerate all files under the directory but directly returns the path of directory**"

To return list of files with path I just need to use `multiple` in `input` like so.

```html
<input type="file" id="fileDialog" multiple />
```

I also found a working code from [How to find out if reading dir is completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149553/how-to-find-out-if-reading-dir-is-completed) to read and return directories and files with pull path recursively. Thanks again to both.